# fdelete in sas, delete files from a backup

Tags: sas

I want to delete files from backup if there are more than three files.

```
   filename parent '/abc/cde';
```

if is less than three files in parent directory sas code does nothing.
The name of sample file: 
ABC_1117_02MAY2016.txt 
- all have the same length.

if count()>3 then sas code returns all dates from substring: 
02MAY2016,
because I want to delete all files with dates less than the third largest.

```
data all_files;
 keep substr_date;
    did=dopen("parent");
    if dnum(did)>3 then do;
        do i=1 to dnum(did);
        wycinek_z_daty=substr(dread(did,i),10,9);
        output;
end;
end;

run;
```

I sort it

```
proc sort data=all_files;
by descending substr_date;
run;
```

It is what I don't want to delete

```
data backup;
set all_files(obs=3);
run;
```

I create a table with all what I want to delete.

```
proc sql;
create table delete as
select*from all_files except select*from backup;
quit;
```

How I can remove these files that I have in 'delete' table? I know I supposed to use fdelete funtion

```
%macro test;
%do i=1 %to &sqlobs;
fdelete('/abc/cde/ABC_1117_&something. Can I use macro variable for i? because only date in name is changing?)
%end;
%mend;
```

Thanks for help,
aola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the `delete` table, I would write the macro like so:

```
%macro delete_file(file=);
  fdelete("&file.");
%mend;
```

Then you can call it:

```
proc sql;
  select cats('%delete_file(file=abc_1117_',substr_date,')')
    into :dellist separated by ' '
    from delete;
quit;

&dellist.;
```

I would probably just save the whole filename in `delete` dataset and then use that rather than hardcoding `abc_1117_`, but that's your call.